# ChartJS define default Y axis dataset

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart that I can barely see the «Activities» column and I was wondering if I could define the default Y axis to a certain dataset?

I'd like to improve the visibility / UI of the chart. Any suggestions on how can I do it?

The following example also can be seen in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3g2o5pfd/).

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('my-chart').getContext('2d');

new Chart(ctx,
{
type: 'bar',
data:
{
    labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    datasets: 
    [
        {
            label: 'Activities',
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            data: [5, 33, 24, 6, 14, 5, 8, 10, 5, 4, 0, 0],
        },
        {
            label: 'Grand total',
            backgroundColor: '#eb4034',
            data: [0, 300.96, 482.98, 153.75, 463.71, 70.36, 3025.80, 1142.00, 2266.89, 1660.50, 0, 0],
        },
    ]
},
options:
{
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    elements:
    {
        line:
        {
            tension: 0.4,
            borderJoinStyle: 'round',
        }
    },
    tooltips:
    {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false,
    },
    hover:
    {
        mode: 'nearest',
        intersect: true
    },
    scales:
    {
        xAxes: 
        [
            {
                gridLines:
                {
                    display: false
                },
            }
        ],
        yAxes: 
        [
            {
                gridLines:
                {
                    display: true,
                    color: '#d9dffa',
                    drawBorder: false,
                    offsetGridLines: false,
                    drawTicks: false,
                    borderDash: [3,5],
                    zeroLineWidth: 1,
                    zeroLineColor: '#d9dffa',
                    zeroLineBorderDash: [3,4]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    legend: 
    {
        display: false,
    }
},
});
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="my-chart"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put an id per axis y, called yAxisID, to disambiguate the scale at will. Try this code:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('my-chart').getContext('2d');

new Chart(ctx,
{
type: 'bar',
data:
{
    labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    datasets: 
    [
        {
            label: 'Activities',
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            data: [5, 33, 24, 6, 14, 5, 8, 10, 5, 4, 0, 0],
            yAxisID: "yActvity"
        },
        {
            label: 'Grand total',
            backgroundColor: '#eb4034',
            data: [0, 300.96, 482.98, 153.75, 463.71, 70.36, 3025.80, 1142.00, 2266.89, 1660.50, 0, 0]
        },
    ]
},
scales: {
  yActvity: {
    min: 0,
    max: 40,
  }
},
options:
{
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    elements:
    {
        line:
        {
            tension: 0.4,
            borderJoinStyle: 'round',
        }
    },
    tooltips:
    {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false,
    },
    hover:
    {
        mode: 'nearest',
        intersect: true
    },
    scales:
    {
        xAxes: 
        [
            {
                gridLines:
                {
                    display: false
                },
            }
        ],
        yAxes: 
        [
            {
                gridLines:
                {
                    display: true,
                    color: '#d9dffa',
                    drawBorder: false,
                    offsetGridLines: false,
                    drawTicks: false,
                    borderDash: [3,5],
                    zeroLineWidth: 1,
                    zeroLineColor: '#d9dffa',
                    zeroLineBorderDash: [3,4]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    legend: 
    {
        display: false,
    }
},
});
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="my-chart"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the options.scales.y.ticks.callback which is a function taking the value in y, and returns a new label.

Next example shows with callback being
options.scales.y.ticks.callback = (value) => (value / 1000) + 'K'

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('my-chart').getContext('2d');

new Chart(ctx,
{
type: 'bar',
data:
{
    labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    datasets: 
    [
        {
            label: 'Activities',
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            data: [5, 33, 24, 6, 14, 5, 8, 10, 5, 4, 0, 0],
        },
        {
            label: 'Grand total',
            backgroundColor: '#eb4034',
            data: [0, 300.96, 482.98, 153.75, 463.71, 70.36, 3025.80, 1142.00, 2266.89, 1660.50, 0, 0],
        },
    ]
},
options:
{
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    elements:
    {
        line:
        {
            tension: 0.4,
            borderJoinStyle: 'round',
        }
    },
    tooltips:
    {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false,
    },
    hover:
    {
        mode: 'nearest',
        intersect: true
    },
    scales:
    {
        xAxes: 
        [
            {
                gridLines:
                {
                    display: false
                },
            }
        ],
        y: {
          ticks: {
            callback: (value) => (value / 1000) + 'K'
          }
        },
        yAxes: 
        [
            {
                gridLines:
                {
                    display: true,
                    color: '#d9dffa',
                    drawBorder: false,
                    offsetGridLines: false,
                    drawTicks: false,
                    borderDash: [3,5],
                    zeroLineWidth: 1,
                    zeroLineColor: '#d9dffa',
                    zeroLineBorderDash: [3,4]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    legend: 
    {
        display: false,
    }
},
});
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="my-chart"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```